# duplicate Rails 4 asset fingerprint file on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting duplicate asset fingerprint javascript file on Heroku production.

This initially creates around 3-4 files then after a while (a day), it creates another set of those files again. Also every time I refresh those files get rotated in the source.

On production.rb:

```
  config.assets.enabled = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true


config.assets.precompile += %w( '.woff', '.eot', '.svg', '.ttf', '*.css.scss', application_user.js, popcorn.js )
```

On application.rb:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely this doesn't matter?

---

**Structure**

The Rails structure is such that it should allow you to use whatever fingerprinted file you need, and it will show (using the dynamic [javascript include helpers](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag))

If you're unable to read a particular file because it's not exactly the same as it was before is, in my opinion, a highlight of a poor system design

---

**Files**

I think I remember your issue from another day -- you can just use the helper method to call the files you need. It shouldn't cause any issues with the different names. It's all part of the `asset pipeline`

I'd recommend looking into how you're calling the files - if you're trying to call the hashed filename directly, you're going to have an issue

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! I think this is largely due to assets not being successfully uploaded to S3. Apparently according to Amazon, S3 is not recommended to host those assets and it's intended for uploaded files only

Comment: I think it's probably wise to disable serving from S3 for those javascript and scss files only. although I need to look around to find a solutiion for this...

Comment: Hey no problem! S3 is a great repo for storing files - I think you're getting confused between storage & access. Accessing the files through a CDN like [CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168926-How-do-I-use-CloudFlare-with-Amazon-s-S3-Service-) will not be dependent on where the files are stored, making S3 a viable option

Comment: Are you using the [asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) gem? We server all our assets from S3 using this gem & it works flawlessly

Comment: Yes I am using that gem. Something really weird is that this used to work flawlessly but now it doesn't work.. I'm currently doing precompilation from heroku staging site to see if there any errors...

Comment: How are you calling the files you need? I remember you were doing some different compilation methods on those files? I think this is the core of the issue

Comment: I'm just doing... `heroku run rake assets:clean` then `heroku run rake assets:precompile`

Comment: This used to work before flawlessly but now it's not uploading and it seems it's unique to production as I'm not getting any errors during precompilation on staging but I do with SASS in production

Comment: Can I see your Heroku link? I'd love to see the error live

Comment: So this file `//commstratvirtualconference.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/application_user-82c5c95c975b29801e4f2a75be6b3e4b.js` keeps changing its name when you refresh but somehow css file doesn't change

Comment: Oh yes! Hmmmmmmmmmm let me look at it a little further

Comment: I just went ahead and fixed the precompiling issue and this seems to have solved the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! Any further questions, please just ask!